# Weird numpy array element check behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been chasing an error for a long time. I have finally tracked it down to this:

```
a = 3*np.arange(0.5,1.6,0.1)
b = 3*np.array([0.5,1,1.5])

for c in a:
   print(c in b)
```

I would expect 3 of the elements of `a` to appear in `b` but when I execute the code above I only get that one of them is in `b`. Is anyone able to explain whats going on here?

Comment: Try changing it to `print(c, c in b)` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Print the `repr()` of each element - in the `a` array, you'll see the values `2.9999999999999996` and `4.499999999999999` instead of `3.0` and `4.5`. You should never directly compare floats to each other. If you want to have infinite precision, I believe you can use the `decimal` module in this case.